# Parsing a web page for text

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to search a webpage for a word "Green". It tells me things are fine but if it finds "Red" it tells me things are bad. What I've done below is very simple but I'm thinking its enough to ask the question.

```
$web = Invoke-WebRequest http://myip/vrsinfo/aghealth/DISTAGAR
$web.ToString() -split "[`r`n]" | Select-String "Green"
```

Here is what it returns

```
name="agSolarwindsHealth" value=Green readonly>
```

Here is what I've tried so far

```
if (name="agSolarwindsHealth" value=Green readonly>) {
    'This number is  1'
} else {
    'This number is  not 1'
}
```

```
Error
name=agSolarwindsHealth : The term 'name=agSolarwindsHealth' is not recognized
as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:3 char:5
+ if (name="agSolarwindsHealth" value=Green readonly>)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (name=agSolarwindsHealth:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: this `(name="agSolarwindsHealth" value=Green readonly>)` is not valid code. you need to use something that is both valid code AND that returns something that can be interpreted as a False/True value.this `$web.tostring() -split "[`r`n]" | select-string "Green"` would be a valid bit of code and - if the result is anything that can be interpreted as a False/True - will work.

Comment: `$web` has a property `ParsedHtml` that contains the already parsed HTML document structure. Use that instead of doing a string search. `$web.ParsedHtml.getElementsByName('agSolarwindsHealth') | Select-Object -First 1 -Expand value`